# Which function is used to initialize the static class member?

Tags: c++, static-members, argument-dependent-lookup

I have a question about which function is chosen to init a static class member.

```
//Base.h

class Base
{
private:
    static int count;
    static int countInit()
    {
        return 10;
    }
public:
    Base()
    {
    }
};

//and Base.cpp
static int countInit()
{
    return 0;
}
int Base::count=countInit();//member function is used.
static int local_count=countInit();//the local one in Base.cpp
```

The variable `Base::count` is initialized with `Base::countInit()` rather than the `countInit()` defined in Base.cpp. But the `local_count` is initialized by the local `countInit`. So, I wonder, is there a rule like **Koenig lookup** within this case?

Comment: So `int Base::count=countInit();` calls the member?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, Yes, it does. I wasn't aware that happened.

Comment: where is "int Base::count=countInit();" invoked ? cause static member function Base::countInit() count not be invoked only by countInit() out of the scope of class Base.

Comment: Try ::countInit(), does that make a difference?

Comment: @NeilKirk if call the ::countInit(), the local countInit is used.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After you write `int Base::count` you are in class `Base`, so static function of class will be called. *Unqualified lookup* will be used here

from 3.4.2/13

> A name used in the definition of a static data member of class X (9.4.2) (after the qualified-id of the static
> member) is looked up as if the name was used in a member function of X.

from 9.4.2

> The definition for a static data member shall appear in a namespace
> scope enclosing the member’s class definition. In the definition at namespace scope, the name of the static
> data member shall be qualified by its class name using the :: operator. **The initializer expression in the
> definition of a static data member is in the scope of its class**
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> class process {
> static process* run_chain;
> static process* running;
> };
> process* process::running = get_main();
> process* process::run_chain = running;
> ```